# Deferencing memory from ctypes in Python when using windows API

Tags: python, qt, memory-management, ctypes, pyside2

I am using PySide2 to build a GUI in python that requires calling Windows API using ctypes. I have done some C++ and am familiar with memory allocation / deallocation, but am not confident in the context of calling C from python.

I have a couple of use-cases I would like to double check (minimum examples below), as really don't want to miss a possible memory leak. Any help would be much appreciated to ensure my understanding is correct.

**1) Pointer to structure managed by Windows / Qt**

```
class NCCALCSIZE_PARAMS(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("rgrc", RECT * 3), ("lppos", POINTER(PWINDOWPOS))]

LPNCCALCSIZE_PARAMS = POINTER(NCCALCSIZE_PARAMS)

rect = cast(msg.lParam, LPNCCALCSIZE_PARAMS).contents.rgrc[0]
rect.left += thickness
```

[NCCALCSIZE_PARAMS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/ns-winuser-nccalcsize_params) is a structure managed by Windows Qt to calculate window size. I think the memory for this will be managed on the Qt / C++ side, and so there is no need to de-reference the block the POINTER points to, so I can just let it go out of scope? for rect = cast(), I believe this is also a pointer to the same memory address, so I can also let it go out of scope.

**2) Passing initialised ctypes structure by reference**

```
class MARGINS(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("cxLeftWidth", c_int),
                ("cxRightWidth", c_int),
                ("cyTopHeight", c_int),
                ("cyBottomHeight", c_int)
                ]

margins = MARGINS(1, 1, 1, 1)
dwm.DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea(msg.hWnd, ctypes.byref(margins))
```

In this instance, a class is initialised on the python side as a ctypes structure. A reference to it is passed to a windows dll. Because the reference is passed straight to the function, and the structure was initialised on the python side, there is no need to deallocate memory?

**3)  Using ctypes from_address()**

```
def nativeEvent(self, event, message):
    msg = MSG.from_address(message.__int__())
    return QtWidgets.QWidget.nativeEvent(self, event, message)
```

This is used to handle internal windows messages, which are structures containing information about the window. message is passed to Qt's nativeEvent after use, and so windows / C++ should handle the memory release. It is read into python with ctyes [MSG class](https://epydoc.sourceforge.net/stdlib/ctypes.wintypes.MSG-class.html) using ctyes from_adress() function. I believe ctypes from_address() just returns a python instance of whatever is at that address, and so in this case there is also no need to dellocate memory?

Comment: I admit I've never worked a lot with CTypes, but I'm curious: why do you need to do this? Besides, it's unclear what `MSG` and its `from_address` actually are.

Comment: thanks for the comment I've updated the MSG section. I am trying to build an app on windows which does not show the title bar and border (the 'non-client area'), so I can implement these myself as much as possible. Unfortunately the Qt flag FramelessWindowHint disables all native resizing etc. behvaiours. Some of these can be regained by using Qt calls e.g. StartSystemMove. But these are buggy and native windows features like snapping are broken. So the solution is to keep the client frame but hide it, and this is only possible with windows API calls.

Comment: It is the same problem that  e.g. https://epydoc.sourceforge.net/stdlib/ctypes.wintypes.MSG-class.html addresses

Comment: Side note: `("lppos", POINTER(PWINDOWPOS))` should be `("lppos", PWINDOWPOS)` (*lp* *pos* not *lpp* *os*).